# Linear dependency and independency verification

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I would like to verify if this problem is solved correctly:

Determine if A is linearly dependent or independent in $\mathbb {R}^3$

$$ A=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -1 \\
        0 \\
        2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        -4\\
        2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
        2 \\
        0 \\
        4 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

First thing I did was taking A into a matrix with the 3rd power:

$$ A^3=
        \begin{vmatrix}
        -25 & -36 & 50 \\
        0 & -64 & 0 \\
        50 & 104 & -100 \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$$
From here on it's Gaussian elimination
$$\frac{(F_1*-2)}{F_3}=F_1$$
$$ A^3=
        \begin{vmatrix}
        1 & \frac{9}{3} & 1 \\
        0 & -64 & 0 \\
        50 & 104 & -100 \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$$
$$\frac{F_2}{64}=F_2$$
$$ A^3=
        \begin{vmatrix}
        1 & \frac{9}{3} & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        50 & 104 & -100 \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$$
$$\frac{F_3}{-100}=F_3$$
$$ A^3=
        \begin{vmatrix}
        1 & \frac{9}{3} & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{104}{100} & 1 \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$$
$$(F_3*2)+F_1=F_3$$
$$ A^3=
        \begin{vmatrix}
        1 & \frac{9}{3} & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1.44 & 3 \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$$

We can write this as a system of equations already
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        x_1 & +\frac{9}{13}x_2 & +x_3 & = 0 \\
        0x_1& +x_2 &+0x_3  & =0 \\
        0x_1& +1.44x_2 &+3x_3  & =0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
From the second ecuation we know that $x_2=0$ , if we add $x_2=0$ into the third equation we find out that $x_3=0$ and if we do this with the first equation we find out that $x_1=0$ as well.

Answer: Since all of our coefficients $x_1$,$x_2$ and $x_3$ are equal to cero, then $A$ is linearly independent.

Comment: There is no need to take the third power. You cannot divides rows, you can only add multiples of rows to each other. If you know what the determinant is, you can also check that the determinant of A is not zero.

Comment: Is $A$ the set of these vectors? So are you trying to determine if $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-2\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}0\\-4\\2\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\4\end{pmatrix}$ are linearly independent?

Comment: Why in the world would you take the third power of that poor matrix?? And if already you can deal with the matrix formed by the vectors itself, why not directly calculate its determinant and check it isn't zero and thus the vectors are lin. ind.? Much faster...

Comment: I took the matrix to the third power because the problem asks if the matrix is linearly dependent in real numbers to the third power. Do I simply ignore that and do it as if they only asked for real numbers? @DonAntonio

Comment: @Dave Right, considering that we are dealing with real numbers to the third power

Comment: @RafaelMartínez That question is a little odd: the *matrix* is linearly dependent? Perhaps you meant the vectors forming the matrix...but if the vectors of a matrix $\;A\;$ are lin. indep., then for **any** $\;n\in\Bbb Z\;$ the vectors forming $\;A^n\;$ are lin. indep. This follows, from example, from the product theorem for determinants.

Comment: By real numbers to the third power you mean $\Bbb R^3$? This is the vector space of 3 dimensional column vectors whose entries are in $\Bbb R$ (real numbers). So the vectors you have are in $\Bbb R^3$, so to determine if they are linearly independent you do not need to raise anything to the power of $3$. One way to determine if they are linearly independent is put them in a matrix, and compute the determinant of that matrix. They will be linearly independent if and only if that determinant is nonzero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do elementary operations directly on the matrix itself and save a lot of time:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\!-1&0&2\\
0&\!-4&2\\
2&0&4\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3+2R_1}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
\!-1&0&2\\
0&\!-4&2\\
0&0&8\end{pmatrix}$$

and we already have our matrix row-reduced and no all-zeros row in it$\;\implies\;$ the matrix is regular and thus the vectors are lin. ind.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if those vectors are linearly independent, then just express them as column vectors in a matrix $A$ and row reduce. If you can reach the identity, then the column space is linearly independent which implies that the vectors are all linearly independent (why?)

Of course, if you can reduce down to $I$, then $detA \neq 0$, which means that the solution:
$$Ax = 0$$
Only has the trivial solution $\implies$ they are linearly independent. This is because there is a unique $A^{-1}$ that solves the system (by definition of being invertible and uniqueness of inverse).